# Is there any possibality to run docker-autoheal (or similar..) for an Image that already running without having the dockerfile?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have an image that I cannot miss on anything on it, but I need any other way to monitor it or applying any other docker-autoheal alternative tool, the issue that most of the docker-autoheal documaintaion needs to modify the image configuration and add a health check to it (which is not possible to my situation).

My main goal here is to auto restart the image after it's stopped/failed immedialty.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve] and explain a little more about the problem you're having?  On any container you can set a [restart policy](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/#use-a-restart-policy) to cause Docker to restart it automatically if the process in it fails.

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze the problem that the restart policy will not work sometimes, especially that the container could be on a running state but actually it's not perform the main function, that's why I'm trying to find something that could stimulate th3 health check option.

Answer (score -1):

Hi you can use docker commit in order to make changes to the image :)

Comment: `docker commit` is almost never a best practice; it leads to images you can't recreate or apply security patches to.